# To Set Position for Chart Title without overlaying Chart using NPOI nuget Excel Package

Tags: excel, charts, overlay, title, npoi

```
   ISheet chartSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("PieChart");
   var headerCellStyle1 = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
   var headerFont1 = workbook.CreateFont();
   headerFont1.Boldweight = (short)FontBoldWeight.Bold;
   headerFont1.Color = HSSFColor.Black.Index; 
   headerCellStyle1.SetFont(headerFont1);
   chartSheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
   int cellIndex = 0; 
   var row = chartSheet.CreateRow(0);
   foreach (var record in recordPie)
   {
       var cellpie = row.CreateCell(cellIndex);
       cellpie.SetCellValue(record.ModuleName);
       cellpie.CellStyle = headerCellStyle1; 
       cellIndex++;
   }
   cellIndex = 0; 
   row = chartSheet.CreateRow(1);
   foreach (var record in recordPie)
   {
       row.CreateCell(cellIndex).SetCellValue((double)record.NumberOfRecords);
       cellIndex++;
   }
   var anchor = chartSheet.DrawingPatriarch.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 20);

   var chart = chartSheet.DrawingPatriarch.CreateChart(anchor);

   var chartData = chart.ChartDataFactory.CreatePieChartData<string, double>();
   var xSeries = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 3); 
   var ySeries = new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 3); 

   _ = chartData.AddSeries(
       DataSources.FromStringCellRange(chartSheet, xSeries),
       DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(chartSheet, ySeries));

   chart.SetTitle("No. of Risk Assessments");
   chart.Plot(chartData);
```

This is My Code for creating Pie chart using NPOI Package For Excel Chart Generation.

```
 chart.SetTitle("No. of Risk Assessments");
```

Here My Chart Title overlay above My PieChart so I want to position My title at top/bottom of pie chart without overlaying it. I tried to position but it wasn't supporting. How to position chart title using NPOI package?